# When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, quotes

Should or should I not wrap quotes around variables in a shell script?

For example, is the following correct:

```
xdg-open $URL
[ $? -eq 2 ]
```

or

```
xdg-open "$URL"
[ "$?" -eq "2" ]
```

And if so, why?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells

Comment: This question gets a lot of duplicates, many of which are not about variables, so I retitled to "value" instead of "variable".  I hope this helps more people find this topic.

Comment: @codeforester What's up with the reverted edit?

Comment: See also [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: Related: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/6862601) as well.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Bash is a hack that ended up being used well beyond what its designs considered. There are better ways to do things but there is no "correct / secure way". I say this because there are a lot of references here that will all have opposing opinions and it can become very confusing especially for people that are used to the newer languages and tools designed for specific tasks.

Comment: @Heavy Gray: What do you suggest instead? [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)?

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash which covers complications related to quoting an `ssh` command line. In very brief, you need to escape some shell metacharacters from both the local and the remote shell. Using a here document if you can might alleviate the problems somewhat.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817504/1765658

Answer (score 258, accepted):

General rule: quote it if it can either be empty or contain spaces (or any whitespace really) or special characters (wildcards). Not quoting strings with spaces often leads to the shell breaking apart a single argument into many.

`$?` doesn't need quotes since it's a numeric value. Whether `$URL` needs it depends on what you allow in there and whether you still want an argument if it's empty.

I tend to always quote strings just out of habit since it's safer that way.

Comment: so you would alternate between quoting and non-quoting variables in your scripts? thanks for your response

Comment: I think it's worth adding to this answer what the effect of not quoting a variable with spaces would be.

Comment: do you only have to quote string variables?

Comment: @Cristian: All shell variables are string variables (well, except thing like arrays).  When a shell variable is set to an integer, it's still a string, it's just that the string happens to be a sequence of digits.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for the response, does that mean the programmer has to know in advance what kind of variable it will be, like if it will be a single character or number or boolean, and add quotes appropriately? or should you just add quotes to every variable? thanks for the reply!

Comment: Note that "spaces" really means "any whitespace".

Comment: @Cristian: If you aren't sure what might be in the variable, it's safer to quote it.  I tend to follow the same principle as paxdiablo, and just make a habit of quoting everything (unless there's a specific reason not to).

Comment: If you don't know the value of IFS, quote it no matter what. If `IFS=0`, then `echo $?` can be very surprising.

Comment: Important: You also need to quote if the variable's value may contain wildcards such as \*.

Comment: Quote based on the context, not on what you expect the values to be, otherwise your bugs will be worse.  For example, you are sure that none of your paths have spaces, so you think you can write `cp $source1 $source2 $dest`, but if for some unexpected reason `dest` doesn't get set, the third argument just disappears, and it will silently copy `source1` over `source2` instead of giving you an appropriate error for the blank destination (as it would have if you had quoted each argument).

Comment: Derek, I believe that would be adequately covered by my 'contain spaces or be blank' comment.

Comment: @paxdiablo "I tend to always quote strings just out of habit since it's safer that way."; agree, my first tought was then: "always quote `Bash` variable"

Comment: in addition, there are two cases where quotes are not necessary variable assignmnent `a=$b` and tests between `[[` ... `]]`, in the later the double quotes can change the meaning for example `a=*`,  `[[ x = $a ]]` succeeds whereas `[[ x = "$a" ]]` fails

Comment: `quote it if...` has the thought process backwards - quotes aren't something you add when you need to, they're something you remove when you need to. Always wrap strings and scripts in single quotes unless you **need** to use double quotes (e.g. to let a variable expand) or **need** to use no quotes (e.g. to do globbing and file name expansion).

Answer (score 173):

In short, quote everything where you do not require the shell to perform word splitting and wildcard expansion.

Single quotes protect the text between them verbatim.  It is the proper tool when you need to ensure that the shell does not touch the string at all.  Typically, it is the quoting mechanism of choice when you do not require variable interpolation.

```
$ echo 'Nothing \t in here $will change'
Nothing \t in here $will change

$ grep -F '@&$*!!' file /dev/null
file:I can't get this @&$*!! quoting right.
```

Double quotes are suitable when variable interpolation is required.  With suitable adaptations, it is also a good workaround when you need single quotes in the string.  (There is no straightforward way to escape a single quote between single quotes, because there is no escape mechanism inside single quotes -- if there was, they would not quote completely verbatim.)

```
$ echo "There is no place like '$HOME'"
There is no place like '/home/me'
```

No quotes are suitable when you specifically require the shell to perform word splitting and/or wildcard expansion.

[Word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) (aka token splitting);

```
 $ words="foo bar baz"
 $ for word in $words; do
 >   echo "$word"
 > done
 foo
 bar
 baz
```

By contrast:

```
 $ for word in "$words"; do echo "$word"; done
 foo bar baz
```

(The loop only runs once, over the single, quoted string.)

```
 $ for word in '$words'; do echo "$word"; done
 $words
```

(The loop only runs once, over the literal single-quoted string.)

Wildcard expansion:

```
$ pattern='file*.txt'
$ ls $pattern
file1.txt      file_other.txt
```

By contrast:

```
$ ls "$pattern"
ls: cannot access file*.txt: No such file or directory
```

(There is no file named literally `file*.txt`.)

```
$ ls '$pattern'
ls: cannot access $pattern: No such file or directory
```

(There is no file named `$pattern`, either!)

In more concrete terms, anything containing a filename should usually be quoted (because filenames can contain whitespace and other shell metacharacters).  Anything containing a URL should usually be quoted (because many URLs contain shell metacharacters like `?` and `&`).  Anything containing a regex should usually be quoted (ditto ditto).  Anything containing significant whitespace other than single spaces between non-whitespace characters needs to be quoted (because otherwise, the shell will munge the whitespace into, effectively, single spaces, and trim any leading or trailing whitespace).

When you know that a variable can only contain a value which contains no shell metacharacters, quoting is optional.  Thus, an unquoted `$?` is basically fine, because this variable can only ever contain a single number.  However, `"$?"` is also correct, and recommended for general consistency and correctness (though this is my personal recommendation, not a widely recognized policy).

Values which are not variables basically follow the same rules, though you could then also escape any metacharacters instead of quoting them. For a common example, a URL with a `&` in it will be parsed by the shell as a background command unless the metacharacter is escaped or quoted:

```
$ wget http://example.com/q&uack
[1] wget http://example.com/q
-bash: uack: command not found
```

(Of course, this also happens if the URL is in an unquoted variable.) For a static string, single quotes make the most sense, although any form of quoting or escaping works here.

```
wget 'http://example.com/q&uack'  # Single quotes preferred for a static string
wget "http://example.com/q&uack"  # Double quotes work here, too (no $ or ` in the value)
wget http://example.com/q\&uack   # Backslash escape
wget http://example.com/q'&'uack  # Only the metacharacter really needs quoting
```

The last example also suggests another useful concept, which I like to call "seesaw quoting". If you need to mix single and double quotes, you can use them adjacent to each other. For example, the following quoted strings

```
'$HOME '
"isn't"
' where `<3'
"' is."
```

can be pasted together back to back, forming a single long string after tokenization and quote removal.

```
$ echo '$HOME '"isn't"' where `<3'"' is."
$HOME isn't where `<3' is.
```

This isn't awfully legible, but it's a common technique and thus good to know.

As an aside, scripts [should usually not use `ls` for anything.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)  To expand a wildcard, just ... use it.

```
$ printf '%s\n' $pattern   # not ``ls -1 $pattern''
file1.txt
file_other.txt

$ for file in $pattern; do  # definitely, definitely not ``for file in $(ls $pattern)''
>  printf 'Found file: %s\n' "$file"
> done
Found file: file1.txt
Found file: file_other.txt
```

(The loop is completely superfluous in the latter example; `printf` specifically works fine with multiple arguments. `stat` too.  But looping over a wildcard match is a common problem, and frequently done incorrectly.)

A variable containing a list of tokens to loop over or a wildcard to expand is less frequently seen, so we sometimes abbreviate to "quote everything unless you know precisely what you are doing".

Comment: This is a variant of (part of) an answer I posted to a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277037/printing-asterisk-in-bash-shell).  I am pasting it here because this is succinct and well-defined enough to become a canonical question for this particular problem.

Comment: I will note that this is item #0 and a recurring theme on the http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls collection of common Bash mistakes.  Many, many of the individual items on that list are basically about this issue.

Comment: Token splitting is called word splitting in the Bash reference. See my edit. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html

Comment: @Roland Thanks! I reworded the text to prefer the official term.

Comment: null bytes should get a honorable mention as shit that will change even when they shouldn't, for example: ```NULL="$(php -r 'echo chr(0);')"``` + ```printf "%s" "$NULL" | wc -c``` will print 0...

Comment: @hanshenrik I don't feel that's a suitable topic to include here, though it can indeed be a pesky problem. The shell and various utilities use C strings, which reserve the null byte as string terminator. Some tools like Perl and Python (and some versions of Awk) use a more sophisticated string representation internally, and are able to accommodate completely arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 52):

Here is a three-point formula for quotes in general:

**Double quotes**

In contexts where we want to suppress word splitting and globbing. Also in contexts where we want the literal to be treated as a string, not a regex.

**Single quotes**

In string literals where we want to suppress interpolation and special treatment of backslashes. In other words, situations where using double quotes would be inappropriate.

**No quotes**

In contexts where we are absolutely sure that there are no word splitting or globbing issues or we *do want word splitting and globbing*.

---

**Examples**

**Double quotes**

- literal strings with whitespace (`"StackOverflow rocks!"`, `"Steve's Apple"`)
- variable expansions (`"$var"`, `"${arr[@]}"`)
- command substitutions (`"$(ls)"`, `` "`ls`" ``)
- globs where directory path or file name part includes spaces (`"/my dir/"*`)
- to protect single quotes (`"single'quote'delimited'string"`)
- Bash parameter expansion (`"${filename##*/}"`)

**Single quotes**

- command names and arguments that have whitespace in them
- literal strings that need interpolation to be suppressed ( `'Really costs $$!'`, `'just a backslash followed by a t: \t'`)
- to protect double quotes (`'The "crux"'`)
- regex literals that need interpolation to be suppressed
- use shell quoting for literals involving special characters (`$'\n\t'`)
- use shell quoting where we need to protect several single and double quotes (`$'{"table": "users", "where": "first_name"=\'Steve\'}'`)

**No quotes**

- around standard numeric variables (`$$`, `$?`, `$#` etc.)
- in arithmetic contexts like `((count++))`, `"${arr[idx]}"`, `"${string:start:length}"`
- inside `[[ ]]` expression which is free from word splitting and globbing issues (this is a matter of style and opinions can vary widely)
- where we want word splitting (`for word in $words`)
- where we want globbing (`for txtfile in *.txt; do ...`)
- where we want `~` to be interpreted as `$HOME` (`~/"some dir"` but not `"~/some dir"`)

---

See also:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/6862601)
- [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5163144/6862601)
- [Quotes and escaping - Bash Hackers' Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)
- [When is double quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/201820)

Comment: According to these guidelines, one would get a listing of files in the root directory by writing `"ls" "/"`  The phrase "all string contexts" needs to be qualified more carefully.

Comment: In `[[ ]]`, quoting does matter on the right hand side of `=`/`==` and `=~`: it makes the difference between interpreting a string as a pattern/regex or literally.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: `"ls" "/"` is, in fact, equivalent to `ls /`.

Comment: A good overview, but @BenjaminW.'s comments are worth integrating and ANSI C-quoted strings (`$'...'`) should definitely have their own section.

Comment: @mklement0, indeed they are equivalent.  These guidelines indicate that you should always type `"ls" "/"` instead of the more common `ls /`, and I take that as a major flaw in the guidelines.

Comment: Given that `IFS` governs word splitting, even standard numeric variables should be quoted for maximum protection: `true; echo $?; IFS=0; true; x=$?; echo $x; echo "$x"`

Comment: For **no quotes** you might add variable assignment or `case` :)

Comment: @WilliamPursell: e.g. x="ls -l", $x lists the dir contents and "$x"  (treats as string literal), throws an err saying file command not found as there is no command with "ls -l"

Comment: @k_vishwanath That is true, but not relevant to my point.  The guidelines quoted here (at least, as they appear now.  They seem to have been edited at some point in the past) cover this case, advising no quotes "In contexts where ... we do want word splitting and globbing.

Answer (score 7):

I generally use quoted like `"$var"` for safe, unless I am sure that `$var` does not contain space.

I do use `$var` as a simple way to join lines:

```
lines="`cat multi-lines-text-file.txt`"
echo "$lines"                             ## multiple lines
echo $lines                               ## all spaces (including newlines) are zapped
```

Comment: The final comment is somewhat misleading; the newlines are effectively replaced with spaces, not simply removed.

Comment: What if _multi-lines-text-file.txt_ contains the word `*`? _bash_ is going to replace that with a list of all the files in your current directory. Lol. Not lol

Comment: right, it's only a simple way, not a sure way